# General CSS Solution for Multiline Inline-Block Underline

Tags: html, css

I have a navigation with fixed width `li`s and variable length content in the `span` tags. Most link content are one line, some are multiline.

The problem is I want both the multiline and single line content to have an underline spanning **only the width of the actual content, not the whole div**.

[Here's a jsfiddle showing the issue](https://jsfiddle.net/v6k39LeL/3/). The second and third multiline elements should have a violet underline that *only* spans the width of the content. In it's final form the violet border should also hug the bottom of the container.

### HTML

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <span>one line</span>
  </li><li>
    <span>holy guacamole three lines</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

### CSS

```
ul {
  table-layout: fixed
  text-align: center;

}

li {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 100px;
  height: 60px;
  text-align: center;

  list-style: none;
  border-left: 1px solid #333;
  border-right: 1px solid #333;
}

span {
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 2px solid violet;
}
```

I fear the only solution is hardcoding either the width or underline length, which I really want to avoid as there are many links. Thank you!

Comment: so the second section of your fiddle, you want each line to be underlined with purple colour and should only take up the length of that particular content? I'm I correct?

Comment: Correct Ousmane. Right now it fills up the whole width of the li.

Answer (score 2):

You can absolutely position the `span` within the `li`

```css
ul {
  table-layout: fixed;
  text-align: center;
}

li {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 100px;
  height: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  list-style: none;
  border-left: 1px solid #333;
  border-right: 1px solid #333;
  position: relative;
}

span {
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 2px solid violet;
}

.abs span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%; left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <span>one line</span>
  </li>
  <li class="abs">
    <span>holy guacamole more lines</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Your code addressed my example perfectly, unfortunately it messed up in reality a bit. Setting the span to position absolute makes the span automatically the width of the longest word, in this case guacamole. Is there any way to modify your answer so it still rags itself to the container instead of extremely narrowly, while having dynamic underlining?

Comment: very interesting! but it seems to me that the width of the span is limited to 50% (maximum) of the `li`, or the length of the longest word. Still, a great solution! +1

Comment: @Pyloid I had a feeling that would be the case :) This would only work if you know roughly how wide/tall the text is so you can create that space in the parent. So it works for your example... this is the only other way I can think of, and doesn't seem ideal. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gmRqBR

Comment: Ah, adding individual classes unfortunately doesn't quite work. So close though, thank you for the time. Perhaps the solution lies within there, I'll continue messing with it and if a tweak from your solution pans out I'll accept yours and post the change.